# SheetJS skips first row of Excel sheet on first upload

Tags: javascript, excel, upload, sapui5, sheetjs

I'm using SheetJS to upload excel files and diplay them in a table of SAPUi5.
For some files the upload works fine, but with others I have the following problem:

1. For example with that excel file below, the uploader skips the first row of the excel file. (Not the ones with the headers but the one below: ZPPPP_MAT, ZPPPP_UNT etc). I debugged the code and when calling

   > console.log(oModel.getData());

All of the data is correctly fetched. Only, whenever I reload the page and then upload a file for the first time, the output leaves an empty row below the column headers. When uploading another file, the first row is displayed correctly. And when then again uploading the first file, the first row gets displayed, too.

So there is something happening on the first time I upload something. Do you have any ideas how to debug this, or where my mistake is?

[image: Problem #1]

Comment: Is there any formatting applied to the first row ZPPPP_MAT , Is it formatted as text ? If yes then try removing the first (') and try again.

Comment: @ImranMalek so sorry, for some reason it's working now.. I've no idea what changed. Thank you still, though!